# Date format PHP

Tags: php, date

I am trying to format a date as 2015-07-12 15:00 from the values declared in my variables

```
// unix
$date = 1436713200
// string
$time = '15:00';
```

to get a date format 2015-07-12 15:00 but failing, using this

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date.' '.$time);
```

I get 'A non well formed numeric value encountered'. Can anyone help? I understand it is possibly due to the mix of string and unix but unsure how to get round this.

Comment: Have you tried `$newdate = date('Y-m-d', $date) . ' ' . $time;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instance to avoid timezone issues:

```
$d = date_create('@1436713200'); // creates DateTime instance
$d->setTime(15, 00); // sets current time to desired hours, minutes
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // prints it out with format specified
//⇒ 2015-07-12 15:00:00
```

Comment: That's a +1 from here. I really like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$date =  date('Y-m-d','1436713200');
// string
$time = '15:00';

echo $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($date.' '.$time));
```

Comment: What’s the main goal of formatting `15:00` in this cumbersome way?

Comment: This is not cumbersome

Comment: I did not downvoted this (because it works,) but you get '15:00', concatenate it with date and then format as '15:00'. I see no reason just not to append '15:00' as is.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to provie the $time variable. Unix time is a full date with time.

Use:
`$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);`